# Using 3D imagery in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, autocad, 3d-model, indoor, bim

I have a Lidar Scan from the inside of a building, in the program Leica Cyclon (.ptg .ptz .xyz) and/or Autodesk ReCap (.rcp .pts .rcs .e57). I need to import this data into ArcGIS Scene for 3D viewing.

Is the best way to go about this to use a 3rd party to convert the data into a .LAS and then bring it into ArcGIS Pro?

I used the ASCII 3D to Feature Class tool and then used the Raster Interpolation tool to interpolate multipoints to a raster but it would not work.

Comment: Have to checked out LAStools or probably even better (but I havent used.. just checking their manual) pointzip http://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/pointzip/

Comment: Thanks! so from what I am understanding is, bottom line is I need to convert my data from Autodesk RECAP to .las and from their I can being utilizing it in the Arc platform?

Comment: Yup LAS or ZLAS http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/las-dataset/use-lidar-in-arcgis-pro.htm and then you can package it into a scene layer package and then upload to Online and create a point cloud scene layer and view it in Scene Viewer or 4.x JS API custom app.